# Creating a PaaS using scrum

Tags: scrum, software-development, sprint

If one were to build say a Windows Azure "clone",
what would be considered an increment that is "potentially releasable"?

e.g. Releasable vs shippable?

I can not envision what would be useful to a client with even a four-week sprint.

Answer (score 3):

Oddly enough, I did this years ago. The first releasable increment is someone could pick from a few options (windows web server, lamp server, etc) and it would trigger a build. When the build was done, the person was emailed some login and IP info. This was done in a 2-week sprint. The mechanisms that managed builds and customer communications became much more sophisticated in future sprints, but they worked a professional level of quality at the end of this sprint.

Now, I also want to point out that we chose to take a 2-week sprint to build proof of concepts using 3 different technologies as the backbone in order to better learn which one we wanted to move forward with, so our first releasable increment was actually from sprint 2 (1 month). But that was a choice. We decided the value in building 3 proof of concepts was worth delaying a releasable increment.